# pandas select FROM .... TO

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
C  V  S  D LOC
1  2  3  4  X  
5  6  7  8  
1  2  3  4  
5  6  7  8  Y
9  10 11 12
```

how can i select rows from loc X to Y and inport them in another csv

Answer (score 3):

Use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) for first values of index where `True` in condition:

```
df = df.loc[(df['LOC'] == 'X').idxmax():(df['LOC'] == 'Y').idxmax()]
print (df)
   C  V  S  D  LOC
0  1  2  3  4    X
1  5  6  7  8  NaN
2  1  2  3  4  NaN
3  5  6  7  8    Y
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [133]: df.loc[df.index[df.LOC=='X'][0]:df.index[df.LOC=='Y'][0]]
Out[133]:
   C  V  S  D  LOC
0  1  2  3  4    X
1  5  6  7  8  NaN
2  1  2  3  4  NaN
3  5  6  7  8    Y
```

PS this will select all rows between **first** occurence of `X` and **first** occurence of `Y`